# Convert Cell to Struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I'm trying to access contents of a cell array which has 4 structures.

```
celldisp(tracks_array);
```

gives output:

```
tracks_array{1} =
             kalmanFilter: [1×1 vision.KalmanFilter]
                       id: 0
        totalVisibleCount: 1
                     bbox: [390 171 70 39]
consecutiveInvisibleCount: 0
                      age: 1
tracks_array{2} =
             kalmanFilter: [1×1 vision.KalmanFilter]
                       id: 1
        totalVisibleCount: 1
                     bbox: [459 175 40 24]
consecutiveInvisibleCount: 0
                      age: 1
tracks_array{3} =
             kalmanFilter: [1×1 vision.KalmanFilter]
                       id: 2
        totalVisibleCount: 1
                     bbox: [220 156 159 91]
consecutiveInvisibleCount: 0
                      age: 1
tracks_array{4} =
             kalmanFilter: [1×1 vision.KalmanFilter]
                       id: 3
        totalVisibleCount: 1
                     bbox: [510 159 68 49]
consecutiveInvisibleCount: 0
                      age: 1
```

Then I Use a for loop to iterate through the elements..

```
for elmen = tracks_array
 structtt=cell2struct(elmen(1),{'id','bbox','kalmanFilter','age','totalVisibleCount','consecutiveInvisibleCount'},2);
```

This gives error of

```
Error using cell2struct
Number of field names must match number of fields in new structure.
```

Then I used this inside the for loop

```
disp(elmen)
celldisp(elmen)
```

gives,

```
[1×1 struct]
 elmen{1} =
             kalmanFilter: [1×1 vision.KalmanFilter]
        totalVisibleCount: 1
                     bbox: [390 171 70 39]
 consecutiveInvisibleCount: 0
                       id: 0
                      age: 1
```

I want to access the elements by their field names. How do I do this?

Right now if I try to use getfield it gives this error:

```
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
```

Comment: You can access the fields like this: `disp(tracks_array{1}.kalmanFilter)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an oddity in Matlab when using `for` to iterate through cell arrays. You would expect it to give you the actual element on each iteration, but instead it gives you a cell array containing just one value, which is that element. But it's easy to extract the actual element using `elmen{1}`. So in your code example:

```
for elmen = tracks_array

    % The actual element is the first and only entry in the cell array
    structtt = elmen{1};

    % Display the structure
    disp(structtt);

    % Display a field within the structure
    disp(structtt.totalVisibleCount);

    % The same as above, but using getfield()
    disp(getfield(structtt, 'totalVisibleCount'));
end
```

You can also write the above as a for loop over the cell array, using the `{}` syntax to extract each element

```
for index = 1 : length(tracks_array)
    structtt = tracks_array{index};

    % Display the structure
    disp(structtt);

    % Display a field within the structure
    disp(structtt.totalVisibleCount);

    % The same as above, but using getfield()
    disp(getfield(structtt, 'totalVisibleCount'));
end
```